# XML Nodeset to R dataframe

Tags: r, xml, dataframe, xml2

I have a nodeset I've extracted from an XML file that looks like this:

```
   <section id="A00-A09">
      <desc>Intestinal infectious diseases (A00-A09)</desc>
      <diag>
        <name>A00</name>
        <desc>Cholera</desc>
        <diag>
          <name>A00.0</name>
          <desc>Cholera due to Vibrio cholerae 01, biovar cholerae</desc>
          <inclusionTerm>
            <note>Classical cholera</note>
          </inclusionTerm>
        </diag>
        <diag>
          <name>A00.1</name>
          <desc>Cholera due to Vibrio cholerae 01, biovar eltor</desc>
          <inclusionTerm>
            <note>Cholera eltor</note>
          </inclusionTerm>
        </diag>
        <diag>
          <name>A00.9</name>
          <desc>Cholera, unspecified</desc>
        </diag>
      </diag>
```

How can I convert this into a dataframe in R that would look like:

```
name      desc                  
A00       Cholera               
A00.0     biovar cholerae     
A00.1     biovar eltor          
A00.9     Cholera, unspecified
```

I've looked at a couple of posts covering XML to df in R but they all seem to be specified to the xml file one is working with (which makes sense given xml), but I'm new to extracting data from xml and haven't been able to find something that works on 44487 elements in my xml_NodeSet. FYI, I used `xml2` for parsing the xml file.

Comment: Have you tried using the rvest package in r?  you can use it to extract the nodes you need, then html_text(), and then manipulate the resulting text as you need.

Comment: I have not. Let me read into the documentation for rvest & see if I can get what I need. Thanks!

Comment: Basically you will have a url and pass this to the read_html() command, then search for the specific nodes (like name, and desc and note) and then remove the html tags, so say with tidyverse something like:  `read_html(URL) %>% html_nodes("name") %>% html_text()`, this will give you all the names in your code. Do the same for desc and note, then append to each other .. although I am not 100% sure how to handle those missing notes...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Nadia for the suggestion. There was no URL for the XML file I was working with so I had to use `xml_nodes()` & `xml_text()`.

I did have trouble with the missing values for `note` & luckily after looking at the data this would not be as valuable as I previously anticipated. Thus, I was able to drop it & that made the ask much more reasonable.

Here is what I did:

```
#after extracting the nodeset from my xml file
names <- xml_text(xml_nodes(diags, "name"))
desc <- xml_text(xml_nodes(diags, "desc"))

#convert to lists
names_list <- list(names)
desc_list <- list(desc)

#bring into a dataframe
df <- do.call(rbind, Map(data.frame, A=names_list, B=desc_list))

head(df)
  icdcode                                               name
1     A00                                            Cholera
2   A00.0 Cholera due to Vibrio cholerae 01, biovar cholerae
3   A00.1    Cholera due to Vibrio cholerae 01, biovar eltor
4   A00.9                               Cholera, unspecified
5     A01                     Typhoid and paratyphoid fevers
6   A01.0                                      Typhoid fever
```